Does adding entires to the IPFS `Gateway.PublicGateway` help IPFS resolve content?
I have the following entries in my Gateway.PublicGateway IPFS config
    "PublicGateways": {
      "4everland.io": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": true
      },
      "dweb.link": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": true
      },
      "gateway.pinata.cloud": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs",
          "/ipns"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": false
      },
      "hardbin.com": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": false
      },
      "ipfs.eth.aragon.network": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": false
      },
      "ipfs.io": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": false
      },
      "nftstorage.link": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": true
      },
      "w3s.link": {
        "PathPrefixes": [
          "/ipfs"
        ],
        "UseSubdomains": true
      }
    },

Some content I'm looking for exists on ipfs.io but when I try to ipfs cat QmSSGJfdvXHpmLV3aFDtkT2pmq8dUiySNHbroFoYyromag my node just hangs. Should this gateway config help my node resolve this content?

Turns out they do not. I also asked this question the ipfs forum and got an answer there. Not sure if I'm allowed to link to it though.
